# Why shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation method marked as unavailable?

Tags: ios, swift, screen-orientation

I put this code to a `UIViewController` subclass:

```c
override func shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation(toInterfaceOrientation: UIInterfaceOrientation) -> Bool {
    return true
}
```

and I get this compile time error:

> Cannot override 'shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation' which has been marked unavailable

What is the problem and how do I solve this?

Comment: Did I not answer your question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this code -

```
override var shouldAutorotate: Bool {
    return true
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 8):

`shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation` is deprecated try using `shouldAutorotate()`

Answer (score 0):

I simply changed this code

`shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation`

to this code

```
shouldAutorotate
```